# Can I use the Grotesque Statue artifact on any effect and prevent loss on all affected targets?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The Grotesque Statue artifact reads

> Once per round, you may spend 1 Clue to prevent all Sanity loss from a single effect

Does this mean I can use it on effects that target other players, even effects that target all players, such as the mythos effect that causes every investigator to lose sanity based on how many spells they retain (after losing half).  Could I use a single clue to prevent all Sanity loss from this effect on every single investigator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FAQ/Errata (https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/support/EH%20Errata%20&%20FAQ%202015-01-23.pdf):

> Q Can the Grotesque Statue Artifact prevent other investigators  from
>   losing Sanity?
>
> A No. The Grotesque Statue Artifact’s second effect allows the 
>   investigator to spend one Clue to prevent himself from losing  Sanity
>   from a single effect. It does not allow him to prevent any  other
>   investigator from losing Sanity.